# ssh returns message "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 1"

Tags: ssh, x11

When I ssh into a remote server that's not running any type of X11 desktop environment I get the following message.

```
$ ssh user@server
X11 forwarding request failed

$ ssh user@server ls
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 1
file1
file2
...
```

How can I get rid of these messages?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

These messages can be eliminated through 1 of 3 methods, using just SSH options. You can always send messages to `/dev/null` too but these methods try to deal with the message through configuration, rather than just trapping and dumping them.

#### Method #1 - install xauth

The server you're remoting into is complaining that it cannot create an entry in the user's `.Xauthority` file, because `xauth` is not installed. So you can install it on each server to get rid of this annoying message.

On Fedora 19 you install `xauth` like so:

```
$ sudo yum install xorg-x11-xauth
```

If you then attempt to `ssh` into the server you'll see a message that an entry is being created in the user's `.Xauthority` file.

```
$ ssh root@server
/usr/bin/xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.Xauthority
$
```

Subsequent logins will no longer show this message.

#### Method #2 - disable it via ForwardX11

You can instruct the `ssh` client to not attempt to enable X11 forwarding by inclusion of the SSH parameter ForwardX11.

```
$ ssh -o ForwardX11=no root@server
```

You can do the same thing with the `-x` switch:

```
$ ssh -x root@server
```

This will only temporarily disable this message, but is a good option if you're not able to or unwilling to install `xauth` on the remote server.

#### Method #3 - disable it via sshd_config

This is typically the default but in case it isn't, you can setup your `sshd` server so that X11Forwarding is off, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
X11Forwarding no
```

Of the 3 methods I generally use #2, because I'll often want `X11Forwarding` on for most of my servers, but then don't want to see the `X11....` warnings

#### $HOME/.ssh/config

Much of the time these message won't even show up. They're usually only present when you have the following entries in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file, at the top.

```
ServerAliveInterval 15
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes

GatewayPorts yes
```

So it's this setup, which is ultimately driving the generation of those `X11..` messages, so again, method #2 would seem to be the most appropriate if you want to operate with `ForwardX11 yes` on by default, but then selectively disable it for certain connections from the `ssh` client's perspective.

#### Security

It's generally ill-advised to run with `ForwardX11 yes` on at all times. So if you're wanting to operate your SSH connections in the most secure manor possible, it's best to do the following:

1. Don't include `ForwardX11 yes` in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file
2. Only use ForwardingX11 when you need to via `ssh -X user@server`
3. If you can, disable `X11Forwarding` completely on the server so it's disallowed

#### References

- [SSH: The Secure Shell - The Definitive Guide - 9.3. X Forwarding](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch09_03.htm)

Comment: Can you help me with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470331/mobaxterm-x11-forwarding-issue-with-unix?

Comment: For the record, I received that message when I *was* trying to run X clients on the remote server.  They wouldn't launch because $DISPLAY was not set.  I managed to fix it with your first suggestion: install xauth.

Answer (score 18):

Ran across this today and beat my head for a while until I stumbled across an ssh setting:

If it's RHEL 7 (centOS, OEL, etc), and it has ipv6 disabled, it needs:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: if only the error message related to this...

Comment: you know what's funny? I ran into this today and googled it, found this article, and found my own comment from four years ago and said "OH YEAH THAT'S THE PROBLEM."

Comment: This was the solution in debian 10.

Answer (score 15):

In my case adding this string to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` solved the problem:

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Comment: This worked for me (the server already had xauth installed). Thanks.

Comment: This appeared to solve my issue, but I don't understand why, which is concerning. I have what should be three identical Debian 7 machines, one of which suddenly stopped accepting `locahost` X11 forwarding. X11 forwarding on the other two still works. Any idea what could have changed?

Answer (score 4):

If running the client in verbose mode (`ssh -v user@host`) gives you

```
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.
```

but `xauth` is indeed installed on the server, then it is probably because *sshd* looks for *xauth* executable in wrong location (*/usr/X11R6/bin/xauth* usually). One can fix that by setting

```
XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

in */etc/sshd/sshd_config* (or whatever your server is configured with).

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS 7.  That's the exact error message I was seeing.

Comment: This was my problem, trying to log in remotely to a Mac. There the correct incantation was


XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth

Answer (score 2):

Another slight variation would be if you wanted to stop seeing this message (i.e. stop trying to forward X11) for certain servers but yet keep the default to ForwardX11 yes for all other connections.

For this scenario, you could disable X11 forwarding for a specific host (or range) in your ~/.ssh/config.  Something like this:

```
host 10.1.1.*
ForwardX11 no
```

Acknowledgment: This is a slight embellishment to the existing (and very complete) existing answer - since I couldn't comment!

Answer (score 2):

## Configuring X11 forwarding on a per host basis

In addition to all of the excellent answers already here, you can configure `ForwardX11` on a per host basis, so if only `server` fails like this, you can add an entry to your `~/.ssh/config` file of the following form:

```
Host server server.domain.dom
    ForwardX11 no
```

You can even use entries like this as alliases for whole sets of configurations

```
Host my.server
    HostName server.domain.dom
    User user
    Port 1234
    ForwardX11 no
```

This is especially useful if you have set up [Autocomplete server names for SSH and SCP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181603/6403).

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question after a run in with an `sshd-xauth` bug nearly a decade old.  Two solutions are reported, the first bypassing `xauth`, the second addressing the bug.

---

**Solution 1 - bypass xauth**

- local 
  -- the local machine serving an Xserver.
- remote 
  -- the remote machine serving the application which drives the data going to the Xserver

Remote `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Remote `~/.Xauthority` is empty or does not exist

On local:

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x800 -br -reset   :2 &
DISPLAY=:2 ssh  -fR 6010:/tmp/.X11-unix/X2  user@remote "DISPLAY=:10 xeyes"
```

In the test, local was running Ubuntu 18.05, remote was running Debian Jesse.

I also [posted this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528458/247579) as an answer another question.

---

**Solution 2 - address the *sshd/xauth* bug**

This solution is close to @systempoet 's [solution above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249997/247579), although that alone was not enough.

In addition to modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on remote:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

`/etc/hosts` on remote was also modifed:

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

If either were commented out, the error message

```
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

appeared after the `ssh -X ...` call.
In addition the `/var/log/auth.log` showed the error:

```
sshd[...]: error: Failed to allocate internet-domain X11 display socket
```

Test to produce the bug (before fix):

Local machine:

```
$ Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x800 -br -reset -terminate  :2 &
$ DISPLAY=:2 ssh -X  user@remote
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One important point to note after making the configuration changes is that you'll have to kill sshd so that it picks up the changes:

```
cat /var/run/sshd.pid | xargs kill -1
```

being the root user.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have IPv6 disabled through `/etc/sysctl.conf`, try using [the boot option `disable.ipv6=1`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309461/how-to-disable-ipv6-permanently/337736#337736) instead.

The strange interaction with IPv6 seems to be a bug in OpenSSH: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2143. Related Debian bug reports: https://bugs.debian.org/422327, https://bugs.debian.org/595014.

Answer (score -2):

1. Set the following 2 options in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in your RHEL host

   `X11Forwarding yes
   X11UseLocalhost no`
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd reload`
3. `sudo yum install xauth`
4. ssh back to your RHEL host with -X switch:
   `ssh -X yourname@rhelbox`