# "X11 forwarding request failed" when connecting to github.com

Tags: ssh, x11, git

I'm getting a bizarre error message while using git:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:Itseez/opencv.git
Cloning into 'opencv'
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
(...)
```

I was under the impression that X11 wasn't required for git, so this seemed strange. This clone worked successfully, so this is more of a "warning" issue than an "error" issue, but it seem unsettling. After all, git shouldn't *need* X11. Any suggestions?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111519/ .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you have ssh configured to always attempt to use X11 forwarding. The error message is GitHub telling you that you can't do X11 forwarding from their servers.

Look for `ForwardX11 yes` in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and set it to `no`. This will prevent ssh from attempting to use X11 forwarding for every connection.

Comment: You can disable `FowardX11` just for github.com if you still want to use it for other servers you connect to.

Comment: you might want to mention that Dan's answer points out an important addendum to your solution.  You don't want to turn off ForwardX11 for *all* connections - just for your git cloning hosts.

Answer (score 50):

Note that to disable `ForwardX11` just for github.com you need something like the following in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
    ForwardX11 no

Host *
    ForwardX11 yes
```

The last two lines assume that in general you /do/ want to forward your X connection. This can cause confusion because the following is WRONG:

```
ForwardX11 yes

Host github.com
    ForwardX11 no
```

Which is what I had (and caused me no end of confusion). This is because in .ssh/config, the first setting wins, and isn't overwritten by subsequent customizations.

HTH, Dan.

Comment: Many thanks for "the first setting wins"! Pulled my hair over that especially as swapping the 2 sections from your correct example also does **not** work!

Comment: For other git newbies: you can get the remote URL with `git remote -v`

Comment: The order does matter. I had the wildcard first and had this problem. Putting github.com first works.