# SSH server rejected X11 forwarding request

Tags: centos, x11, xargs

I already asked this question on superuser, but the problem hasn't been solved yet. This problem really bothers me. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

SuperUser Question-- [Link](http://superuser.com/questions/1325239/ssh-server-rejected-x11-forwarding-request)

Env:
centos 7, xshell, xmanager.

I have two centos7 virtual machines, one of which can be successfully open Chrome Browser through X11 forwarding in SSH session, but another one can not.

The normal one：

```
[root@localhost ~]# google-chrome --no-sandbox
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[16458:16458:0523/075723.020611:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(419)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[16458:16458:0523/075723.020636:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(153)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[16458:16458:0523/075723.022497:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(254)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initializat
[16393:16422:0523/075723.081833:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(108)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[root@localhost ~]# [0523/075728.166795:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandb
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

The abnormal one:

```
WARNING! The remote SSH server rejected X11 forwarding request.

[root@yxs ~]# google-chrome --no-sandbox

(google-chrome:10346): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
[root@yxs ~]# [0523/202401.444038:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
^C
[root@yxs ~]# su yxs
[yxs@yxs root]$ google-chrome

(google-chrome:10407): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

The following configurations of the two are almost the same.

The normal one:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#   X11Forwarding no
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep xauth
xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-1.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]# ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
[root@localhost ~]# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0

#enable ipv6
#minimal centos
```

The abnormal one:

```
[root@yxs ~]# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#   X11Forwarding no
[root@yxs ~]#  rpm -qa | grep xauth
xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-1.el7.x86_64
[root@yxs ~]# ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
[root@yxs ~]# echo $DISPLAY

[root@yxs ~]#

#disbale ipv6
#has installd "GNOME Desktop"
```

I tried to execute `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` on the abnormal virtual machine, But when I reboot, the environment variable `$DISPLAY` became empty again.

I just can't open Chrome By command `google-chrome --no-sandbox` through SSH Session in Xshell. But I can use normally through the VNC window on the virtual machine management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because I disable IPv6, I need to add `AddressFamily inet` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.`, I was too careless before. I'm sorry.

The third answer: [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111519/ssh-returns-message-x11-forwarding-request-failed-on-channel-1)