# Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I'm working from the URL I found here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160404025901/http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2009/02/04/logging-in-without-a-password-certificates-ssh/

My ssh client is Ubuntu 64 bit 11.10 desktop and my server is Centos 6.2 64 bit. I have followed the directions. I still get a password prompt on ssh.

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: output from the command you're giving to ssh with the -v flag? should be similar to this http://pastebin.com/xxe57kxg

Comment: also make sure your .ssh folder is `chmod 700`

Comment: assuming you've got root access to the server, `/var/log/auth.log` will tell you why the login is failing.

Comment: Did you password-protect your key?

Comment: @Kevin no, I didn't.

Comment: @UtahJarhead: On the CentOS server, it's likely to be in `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: @Dennis point taken.

Comment: In my case there was an incorrect entry in the hosts file so I wasn't connecting to the machine that I thought I was.

Comment: I had the same Problem. Caused by not using copy-ssh-id but vi and copy pasting the key. However (it is an ssh-rsa ley) the first s of "ssh" was not copied (likely the mouse did not select it). Took me now an hour to figure that, (facepalm)

Comment: In my case it was the newer version of Ubuntu that didn't accept the old key type:  http://superuser.com/questions/962918/pubkeyacceptedkeytypes-and-ssh-dsa-key-type

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere so weird but that was my same problem too. I read your comment and thought "nah, but might as well check." Sure enough, missing the first "s" in "ssh." Thanks a lot `pbcopy`!

Comment: @UtahJarhead My remote server makes no mention whatsoever of a remote key attempt. It just looks like a normal password login.

Comment: If you aren't using the default public keys (id_rsa etc.), then you might need to add your key (the one you have copied to the server) to the current session - ```ssh-add your_key_name```, enter the passphrase, if any.

Comment: Interesting, the chmod `0700` was the answer, but when I did `ssh -v` on the client side it didn't indicate an error related to why the key wasn't accepted, it just said it was trying password next even though my client sent a public key. How do they expect us to diagnose issues with no error information from the server?

Comment: @void.pointer stackoverflow, of course.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post an answer. Setting ACL for `administrators_authorized_keys` worked for me: [PubKey Auth not working
#1306](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1306#issuecomment-451280834)

Comment: chmod 700 fixed it.  Why would I have to do this on CentOS but not Ubuntu?

Comment: I changed mode bits to `750` for `authorized_keys` and it resolved the issue.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer, but in my case, the problem turned out to be none described on this page.  If you are using a newer ssh client (e.g. OpenSSH_8.9p1) with an older openssh server (e.g. OpenSSH_6.7p1) with an RSA keypair, try doing `ssh -v user@remotehost` on the client side.  If it shows `no mutual signature algorithm` when attempting public key authentication, then the problem is likely that the server is using an older (insecure) signature algorithm that is now deprecated in the newer client.  Using a ed25519 keypair at the client (instead of RSA) solves the problem.

Answer (score 862, accepted):

Make sure the permissions on the `~/.ssh` directory and its contents are proper. When I first set up my ssh key auth, I didn't have the `~/.ssh` folder properly set up, and it yelled at me.

- Your home directory `~`, your `~/.ssh` directory and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote machine must be writable only by you: `rwx------` and `rwxr-xr-x` are fine, but `rwxrwx---` is no good¹, even if you are the only user in your group (if you prefer numeric modes: `700` or `755`, not `775`).
  If `~/.ssh` or `authorized_keys` is a symbolic link, [the canonical path (with symbolic links expanded) is checked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152417/why-cant-i-use-public-private-key-authentication-with-ssh-on-arch-linux).
- Your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (on the remote machine) must be readable (at least 400), but you'll need it to be also writable (600) if you will add any more keys to it.
- Your private key file (on the local machine) must be readable and writable only by you: `rw-------`, i.e. `600`.
- Also, if SELinux is set to enforcing, you may need to run `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh` (see e.g. [Ubuntu bug 965663](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/965663) and [Debian bug report #658675](http://bugs.debian.org/658675); this is [patched in CentOS 6](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.2#head-652041430eedc0752937ec8252c52132e574fd2a)).

¹  <sub>Except on some distributions (Debian and derivatives) which have patched the code to allow group writability if you are the only user in your group.</sub>

Comment: I think if you test, you'll find that the public key file just has to be readable by the owner (400), and then only during `ssh-copy-id` or similar. Similarly, the `authorized_keys` file mode check only tests that it is not world or group writeable. It can be 400, too, if you don't need to add more keys to it, or 600 if you do. I didn't feel comfortable making factual changes to your answer beyond the one typo fix, so I'll leave the edits to you.

Comment: @WarrenYoung no matter how many times I set it up, I always forget about ssh-copy-id. I've only had to set the ~/.ssh directory before.

Comment: @Rob: beware that `ssh-copy-id` doesn't exist everywhere. Particularly on older machines, you still have to do it by hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out restorecon. I've been scratching my head at precisely this issue for a while now.

Comment: Oddly enough, I was having problems with an account a friend set up on his VPS getting pubkey auth working. I thought all the permissions were correct, but it's important to remember that `/home/USER` must be `700` or `755`

Comment: Also remember to check the owner and group settings, I used RSYNC to copy over an authorized_keys file and didn't notice that owner/group was set to 1000 instead of root!

Comment: also, add -v to your ssh command to see what happens with that key. `ssh -v user@host`.

Comment: Using CentOS 6.4, I still had to use the `restorecon` command to make it work.

Comment: I found that the permissions on the authorized_keys file were -rw-rw-r-- and worked just fine until I added www-data into my group and then problems begun.  Changing the permissions to -rw------- fixed the problem immediately.  Seems the group permissions are ignored unless there is another user in your group. (Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: Learned so much from this very straight forward answer about user permissions and groups. Thank you.

Comment: It may also be necessary to run `restorecon -R -v ~/` to restore the context on your home directory. Some context settings on my home directory were off from the defaults and despite trying all the other suggestions here and in other posts for over two hours, I still could not connect to my server via SSH public key authentication until I thought to also run `restorecon` on my home `~/` directory after seeing the suggestions here to run it on `~/.ssh`! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I also had to make sure my ~ itself, `$HOME`, was appropriately secure. It was originally 775 for some reason. `chmod 700 $HOME` did the trick.

Comment: `chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh` worked for me to meet the constraints of this answer (RHEL 7)

Comment: for me selinux was the issue. Note: to see if selinux is set use `sestatus` and to disable it `vi /etc/selinux/config` and set to `disabled`

Comment: Due to changes with ssh version 7.0, I had to add "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss" to my ssh server's sshd_config file.  It's just a stopgap measure until I can redo my keys to be RSA keys as DSA keys will be going away.

Comment: Something that helped me: on the remote machine, needed to change ~/.ssh/authorized_key permissions to 600.

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Originally had `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: restorecon didn't work for me, however this did: chcon -R unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 /path/to/users/homedirectory/.ssh/

Comment: Check that you haven't generated your authorized_keys on windows with CRLF line endings!

Comment: I had an oddball home directory (`/data/jenkins`) that `restorecon` didn't fix since it wasn't under `/home`. I had to manually `sudo chcon --reference=~/.ssh/authorized_keys /data/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Throwing that out there in case somebody gets that problem.

Comment: For the newcomers; if you've done the `chmod`-s correctly and it still doesn't work, make sure your user also owns both `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Check by passing for example `sudo ls -l ~/.ssh` and if necessary fix it with `sudo chown username ~/.ssh`. Fix both the directory and the file, re-do chmods, then you should be good.

Comment: +1 for `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh` in case of selinux enabled environment!

Comment: Also note that Putty's private key file format is different than SSH command's format. In my case even I had no password on my ppk file, SSH command was keep asking me its password, but then I realized that it was the ppk file I use for putty, I also had one (same private key) in SSH format and it worked. Note that I was trying to connect to Ubuntu server from Windows

Comment: I understand that my private key should be readable, but why should it be writable?

Comment: I have checked all of these and it is still not working. Any idea what else I can do. (I did not do the last one because it did not seem to apply and restorecon was not installed. Should I install it. I don't know what SELinux is and I would think it is not set to enforcing but how can I check?

Comment: Also ensure that the key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is correct, and is on a single line as expected by `ssh`.

Comment: Checked all my permissions, they look fine. Trying to use a windows openssh client to connect to a centOS host. logs here: https://gist.github.com/Groostav/0dd117be4042951ee6890325a66eddc4 Any help appreciated.

Comment: Applying this fixed the issue on Fedora 30 too

Comment: The problem for me was that the home directory was 770 and that resulted in that the .ssh/authorized_keys was never read, I changed it to 700 and now it works

Comment: @nak thanks for the suggestion. I aborted a usermod operation (intended to change user id so that my user accounts on all machines have the same user id) half way after realizing I needed to disable nfs first. My home directory thus was not set properly to be owned by the new user id.

Comment: I checked all of these and then after the debug method didn't find it I realized that I'd  spelt the file authori**s**ed_keys - whoops. Only one accepted spelling!

Comment: In my case, I mistakenly put the public key to the `~/.ssh/knowns_hosts` file, rather than `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Still the case in 2020

Comment: `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh` works for me in Centos 8

Comment: My remote machine had incorrect permissions (777) on my home directory. Its an experimental set up.

Comment: In my case, I forgot I had limited the ssh users in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to just one user `AllowUsers <username>`. D'oh!

Comment: restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh worked for me in RHEL 8.4

Comment: I am not sure which step fixed for me, but I also did `systemctl stop sshd` and `systemctl start sshd` and after that it worked.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and the solution was not found neither in accepted answer nor in its comment so here it is: in certain configuration, you are maybe required to associate the key file with the host name/ip. this is done by adding an entry to ~/.ssh/config which is approximately 
host 192.153.24.3
        AddKeysToAgent yes
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/relevant_private_key

Comment: in my case SSH version on remote was different and I was using ssh key using ed25519. Switching to new keys based on good old RSA fixed it for me.

Answer (score 237):

If you have root access to the server, the easy way to solve such problems is to run sshd in debug mode, by issuing something like `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222` on the server (full path to sshd executable required, `which sshd` can help) and then connecting from the client with `ssh -p 2222 user@host`. This will force the SSH daemon to stay in the foreground and display debug information about every connection. Look for something like

```
debug1: trying public key file /path/to/home/.ssh/authorized_keys
...
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /path/to/home/
```

If it isn't possible to use an alternative port, you can temporarily stop the SSH daemon and replace it with one in debug mode. Stopping the SSH daemon does not kill existing connections so it is possible to do this through a remote terminal, but somewhat risky - if the connection does get broken somehow at a time when the debug replacement is not running, you are locked out of the machine until you can restart it. The commands required:

```
service ssh stop
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
#...debug output...
service ssh start
```

(Depending on your Linux distribution, first / last line might be `systemctl stop sshd.service` / `systemctl start sshd.service` instead.)

Comment: I just tried this... and it works fine when I'm running `sshd -d`, but fails once I actually run `service sshd start`.  I'm sure it's simple, but I'm not a Linux guru.  Any thoughts?

Comment: For reference, [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/321534/public-key-authentication-fails-only-when-sshd-is-daemon) explains the SELinux solution that addressed my problem.

Comment: I was also having trouble with getting public key authentication to work and I was pretty sure that directory permissions wasn't the problem. After running SSH in debug mode, I quickly found out that I was wrong and permissions were the problems.

Comment: Great advice, my user folder was with the wrong permissions.

Comment: Best answer to help troubleshooting

Comment: I had a similiar problem in Centos 7. Debug (/usr/sbin/sshd -d) shows "trying public key file /path/to/home/.ssh/authorized_keys2". The problem is in Centos7 filename has to be authorized_keys2 instead of authorized_keys.

Comment: Thank you.  Of all reasons, my user wasn't allowed to log in because the shell specified by ansible (/bin/zsh) on user creation didn't exist.  I never would have guessed that.

Comment: My output looks normal "accepted publickey" etc, but I still get prompted https://gist.github.com/parkan/38ce87b3ad2e37694427

Bizarrely, I'm also prompted for `https://the-hostname`, even though it never appears as a http remote, only ssh

Comment: thanks a lot, this debug mode solved my case ("bad ownership"), some of my scripts mistakenly changed my /root ownership to 1000:1000, which I hadn't notice.

Comment: @appleater I had tried everything but with no luck until I found this post. "Learn a man to fish...". Thanks a lot. I also had "bad ownership" in /root.

Comment: +1 because this answer teaches you how to fish vs just giving you a fish.

Comment: Is this dangerous? If you accidentally close your ssh session, you're locked out?

Comment: @Hatshepsut, yes (although you can always just restart the machine). As I said, if you can access other ports, you can just run a second SSH daemon without stopping the normal one, that's definitely less trouble.

Comment: This is the right answer, it's better when you can understand the internal problem by yourself.

Comment: @Tgr can we make `/usr/sbin/sshd -d  -p 2222` and `ssh -p 2222 user@host` the first command proposed on the answer, without `service ssh stop`, for greater safety?

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功 done.

Comment: I agree that starting another sshd instance on an alternate port is a very good troubleshooting technique. I would add that unless run with root  permissions, this sshd will likely fail since `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key` will not be readable -- use `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222`

Comment: For some systems (such as CentOS 7), you need `systemctl stop sshd.service` and `systemctl start sshd.service` to control the sshd instead of using the `service` command.

Comment: My problem was caused by SELinux not being set up for my home directory being shared via NFS. See https://serverfault.com/a/894291/123289 for details and a solution. Thanks to @NRohler for the link to the question.

Comment: You can check the logs by `grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log` first

Comment: This answer pointed me to the light. Then I remembered I had been tinkering with permissions a couple of days before. I owe you big time

Comment: In my case, the issue was due to wrong key encoding and wrong username:
# edit ssh config
`vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
#add line: 
`LogLevel DEBUG3`
# restart sshd 
`systemctl restart sshd`
# log
`cat /var/log/auth.log`
# error found: 
sshd[3778]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or No such file or directory

# look for keys encoding in output
`ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
# Therefore 
`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 256 -f ~/.ssh/id_production`
# connect to my server
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_production root@IP_address`
works

Comment: Instead of temporarily stopping the SSH daemon, you can also create a tunnel through port 22 `ssh -L 2222:localhost:2222` and then `ssh localhost:2222` from another shell to debug. Both commands should be ran on the client.

Comment: This helps. Looking through the log messages I spotted `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for /home/tom`. Bingo. Turns out that group write was turned on for my home dir on the server.

Answer (score 65):

Is your home dir encrypted? If so, for your first ssh session you will have to provide a password. The second ssh session to the same server is working with auth key. If this is the case, you could move your `authorized_keys` to an unencrypted dir and change the path in `~/.ssh/config`.

What I ended up doing was create a `/etc/ssh/username` folder, owned by username, with the correct permissions, and placed the `authorized_keys` file in there. Then changed the AuthorizedKeysFile directive in `/etc/ssh/config` to :

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

This allows multiple users to have this ssh access without compromising permissions.

Comment: ubuntu doc in it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting

Comment: This answer is a salient one & helped me - for anyone wondering if this is the issue - you may see "pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped" in your auth.log; somehow that wasn't enough to prompt me to remember the homedir was encrypted.  Also you may find first logon asks for a passwords, subsequent sessions don't (since it's decrypted whilst the other sessions open).

Comment: Holy crap I've searched wayyyy to long to resolve that issue, tank you so much !

Comment: WRONG... Don't give inaccurate or bad advice. It's not nice. Why do you hate people looking for help? 

kali@kali2:~/.ssh$ ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 root@10.11.1.136
/home/kali/.ssh/config: line 4: Bad configuration option: authorizedkeysfile
/home/kali/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

Comment: @ZackA don't be so angry, mate, you put that config in the wrong file. The AuthorizedKeysFile has to go in the file in your ssh server side config. In an Ubuntu server, I have in a pickyourownname.conf file inside the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/` directory.

Answer (score 63):

Just try these following commands

1. `ssh-keygen`

   Press Enter key till you get the prompt
2. `ssh-copy-id -i root@ip_address`

   (It will once ask for the password of the host system)
3. `ssh root@ip_address`

   Now you should be able to login without any password

Comment: On which server?

Comment: @Amalgovinus Obviously you run this on the client, not the machine you're connecting to - you don't want a copy of your private key on the server! :)

Comment: Please note that generally, allowing remote root logins is not a recommended security practice.

Comment: @nevelis: If it was obvious to them, they wouldn't have asked. Some people are new to ssh-keygen and they might not understand where the public and private keys are. That's why they're here.

Comment: Just elaborating on this answer: I was reluctant to use `ssh-copy-id` because I wasn't familiar with it; I've always just copied the .pub file, and when it didn't work, tried debugging it with `ssh -v`. But today, after half an hour of frustration, I thought what the hell, try using this utility instead. And then it just started working. I had to clear some unwanted keys from `authorized_keys` on my remote machine, but in the end it saved a lot of hassle. Sometimes the easy way really is better. 

Comment: @MichaelScheper That's some solid feedback after 7 years :) Cheers.

Comment: This is black magic.

Comment: I did it manually and it didn't work, but using ssh-copy-id worked. I would have to investigate why!, thanks

Comment: I did this on rocky linux, and it  still asks for my password. I even used ssh -i path to specify the id file. Password works, but I would rather not use one.

Answer (score 52):

After copying keys to the remote machine and putting them inside the `authorized_keys` you've got to do something like this:

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa or id_rsa
```

Comment: Actually no you don't. ssh automatically uses ~/.ssh/id_rsa (or id_dsa) without having to use a key agent.

Comment: This can still be helpful advice if one was to specify a differently named key in ~/.ssh/config (e.g. on host *.mydomain.org...IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_limited_use.pub -- ssh-add ~/.ssh/some_limited_use.pub).

Comment: This has solved my problem with getting password prompt after adding a key.  As 89c3b1b8-b1ae-11e6-b842-48d705 pointed out, the reason to run these commands manually was a non-standard name of a key file.

Comment: As pointed out by above in the comments, if you are using any key besides the default key, it is not added by default to the ssh agent. So be sure to check the key you want to use is in the agent's keychain: `ssh-add -L`

Comment: I had to do ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa Thanks a ton!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

I faced challenges when the home directory on the remote does not have correct privileges. In my case the user changed the home dir to **777** for some local access with in the team. The machine could not connect with ssh keys any longer. I changed the permission to **744** and it started to work again.

Comment: We had this problem too - 755 on the home dirs fixed it

Comment: I had permissions set to 777 and it was ignored, thanks!!!

Comment: Same here. Thanks. Was scratching my head for a while, wtf was happening.

Comment: Yes see the answer here for further detail https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205842/unable-to-login-with-ssh-rsa-key#answer-428848

Comment: This may well be the answer for people who have done the key generation correctly yet are still getting prompted for a password.

Comment: It's worth (on target machine) doing a 'sudo tail -f /var/log/secure' - I got a 'Dec  4 16:54:47 idp sshd[1492]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/dazed/.ssh/authorized_keys'.  Setting via 'chmod 600 /home/dazed/.ssh/authorized_keys' worked

Comment: This was the issue with me too. Thanks

Comment: On my Linux CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) I have to put 700 to the server home dir, it was 740. Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 30):

We ran into the same problem and we followed the steps in the answer. But it still did not work for us. Our problem was that login worked from one client but not from another (the .ssh directory was NFS mounted and both clients were using the same keys).

So we had to go one step further. By running the ssh command in verbose mode you get a lot of information.

```
ssh -vv user@host
```

What we discovered was that the default key (id_rsa) was not accepted and instead the ssh client offered a key matching the client hostname:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa                                    
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply                                        
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa                                    
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply                                        
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: user@myclient                                          
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply                                        
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
```

Obviously this will not work from any other client.

**So the solution in our case was to switch the default rsa key to the one that contained user@myclient.** When a key is default, there is no checking for client name.

Then we ran into another problem, after the switch. Apparently the keys are cached in the local ssh agent and we got the following error on the debug log:

```
'Agent admitted failure to sign using the key'
```

This was solved by reloading the keys to the ssh agent:

```
ssh-add
```

Answer (score 17):

SELinux on RedHat/CentOS 6 [has an issue with pubkey authentication](http://bugs.centos.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=4959), probably when some of the files are created selinux is not setting its ACLs correctly.

To manually fix the SElinux ACLs for the root user:

```
restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh
```

Comment: using openssh client on windows I was able to `ssh root@mymachine` into a CentOS6 `mymachine` without issue, but I have a lower-privilage user that I'd prefer to use, but `ssh regularUser@mymachine` still prompts me for a password. thoughts?

Answer (score 14):

It would be SSH misconfiguration at server end. Server side `sshd_config` file has to be edited, it is located in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

In that file, change variables

- `yes` to `no` for `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`, `PasswordAuthentication`, `UsePAM`
- `no` to `yes` for `PubkeyAuthentication`

(Link to original source is now pointing to spam and was removed).

Comment: As in comments to question check the /var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log. In my case I see "User xxx from xxx not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers" "input_userauth_request: invalid user xxx [preauth]" ( and "rexec line 35: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits" in /var/log/messages although I dunno what that is). To resolve `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add user xxx to AllowUsers list, `service sshd restart` *** BEWARE restarting sshd service with bad sshd_config might lock you out of a box!? ***. That worked.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar problem and followed the steps using the debug mode.

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

This showed the following result

```
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for root from 135.250.24.32 port 54553 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic
```

It was really confusing

```
[root@sys-135 ~]# ls -l /
drwxrwxrwx.   2 root root     4096 Dec 14 20:05 bin
drwxrwxrwx.   5 root root     1024 May  6  2014 boot
drwxrwxrwx.   2 root root     4096 Dec  2  2013 cgroup
drwxrwxrwx.  10 root root     1024 Sep 25 23:46 data
drwxrwxrwx. 124 root root    12288 Dec 16 10:26 etc
drwxrwxrwx.  11 root root     4096 Jan 14  2014 lib
drwxrwxrwx.   9 root root    12288 Dec 14 20:05 lib64
drwxrwxrwx.   2 root root    16384 Jan 10  2014 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx.   2 root root     4096 Jun 28  2011 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root        0 Dec 10 14:35 misc
drwxrwxrwx.   2 root root     4096 Jun 28  2011 mnt
drwxrwxrwx.   4 root root     4096 Nov 24 23:13 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 580 root root        0 Dec 10 14:35 proc
drwxrwxrwx.  45 root root     4096 Dec 16 10:26 root
```

It showed the root directory had permissions for every one.
We changed it so that others would not have permissions.

```
[root@sys-135 ~]# chmod 750 /root
```

The key authentication started working.

Comment: I have same issue. Yesterday, I issued `rsync -av  ./root/ root@THE_HOST:/root` to upload some files from my local working directory, then, this issue occurs (in fact, at first I didn't notice it. After cron jobs in other hosts fails in the next morning, I started digging the reason). The `rsync -av ./root/ root@THE_HOST:/root` command changed the owner and permission of the `/root` directory of the remote host. Fixed the permission, problem solved.

Comment: `Failed publickey for root from 135.250.24.32 port 54553 ssh2` I get same message and issue when I forgot to add the pubkey to a host `authorized_keys`. Adding this comment as in my case, I usually realize my mistake after I checked the debug and all the permissions plus config files #:o<

Answer (score 7):

Ensure that `AuthorizedKeysFile` points to the right location, use `%u` as a placeholder for username:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/%u/authorized_keys
```

It may be that you just need to uncomment the line:

AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

Mind that you must reload ssh service for the changes to take place:

```
service sshd reload
```

Answer (score 7):

In the past I came across some tutorials that describe how to achieve a ssh password-less setup, but some are sadly wrong.
 Let's start over again, and check every step:

1. **FROM CLIENT** - Generate key: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
   Public and private key (`id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`) will be automatically stored in the `~/.ssh/` directory.
   Setup will be easier if you use an empty passphrase. If you are not willing to do that, then still follow this guide, but also check the bullet point below.
2. **FROM CLIENT** - Copy public key to **server** : `ssh-copy-id user@server`
   Client public key will be copied to **server's location** `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
3. **FROM CLIENT** - Connect to server: `ssh user@server`

Now, if it's still not working after the described 3 steps, lets try the following:

- Check `~/.ssh` folder permissions in **client** and **server** machine.
- Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the **server** to ensure that `RSAAuthentication`, `PubkeyAuthentication` and `UsePAM` options aren't disabled, they can be enabled by default with `yes`.
- If you entered a passphrase while generating your client key, then you may try `ssh-agent` & `ssh-add` to achieve password-less connections in your session.
- Check the contents of `/var/log/auth.log` on the **server** to find the issue why key authentication is skipped at all.

Comment: Thanks for listing out the steps! I got to "ssh-copy-id user@server" and realized that I had originally copied over the wrong public key.

Comment: In your first bullet, it should read "check `~/.ssh` folder permissions on client and server for the client and server users"

Answer (score 6):

One thing that I had wrong was the ownership on my home directory on the server system. The server system was set to default:default so I:

```
chown -R root:root /root
```

And it worked. Another Cheap workaround is to Disable StrictModes: StirctModes no. in sshd_config. This will at least tell you if the key exchange and connection protocols are good. Then you can go hunt the bad permissions.

Comment: Me too.   Look at the messages in /var/log/secure.  I saw a message: "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory" ($HOME).  Make sure there isn't write access to $HOME to Group or Other.  I'd never have found this if I didn't have unauthorized root access to the server....

Answer (score 6):

After checking the permissions, and trying several other solutions listed here, I finally just removed the ssh directory on the server, then setup my public key again.

Server commands:

```
rm -rf ~/.ssh
```

Local commands:

```
ssh-copy-id user@192.168.1.1        # where <user> is your username and <192.168.1.1> is the server IP
```

Comment: Exactly what I finished by doing (after checking everything above!) but localy on the host and then It started working. I unfortunetly will never know why it didn't. Thanks.

Comment: debuging and understanding is always good, but when you need the things working NOW - this is it.

Answer (score 5):

In /etc/selinux/config file changing SELINUX to disabled from enforcing made passwordless ssh work successfully.

Earlier I am able to do it on one way. Now from bothways I am able to do passwordless ssh.

Answer (score 5):

At server:

```
$ ls -lh /home
$ sudo chmod 700 /home/$USER
```

It was `directory permission issue`. It was 777 at server, so `I changed it back to 700`. This `fixed` my issue with `ssh password less login failure` even after copying `$USER/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to server `$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: See also https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/

Answer (score 5):

If both the private key and the username/password authentication methods are accepted by the server, and then if the private key fails, it will simply fall back to prompting for a username/password without displaying any error.

You can use the `-vvv` flag to determine if a private key was even attempted, (and which keys specifically), and why the key(s) are failing.  Example: `ssh -T -vvv myHost.com`.  Alternatively, you can use `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `~/.ssh/config`.

A common failure is that the server rejects the key.  In that case, you will see something like this:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myUsername@myServer.com's password:
```

According to the official spec for the SSH protocol (RFC 4252), the authentication packets have the following values:

```
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST    50
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE    51
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS    52
```

This means that `debug3: receive packet: type 51` indicates that the server rejected the key.

Answer (score 4):

Two comments: this will overwrite the original file. I'd just copy the public key generated and do something like:

```
cat your_public_key.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

This will append the key you want to use to the pre-existing list of keys. Also, some systems use the file `authorized_keys2`, so it's a good idea to make a hard link pointing between `authorized_keys` and `authorized_keys2`, just in case.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too about the overwrite, but I didn't have any, so it didn't matter. I created a symlink to the authorized_keys2 but that didn't help.

Comment: Also, check the file/directory permissions. They are described on the website you provided.

Comment: your ~/.ssh dir must be 700
your private key file must be 600
your public key file must be 644
your auth file (on the remote) must be 644

Comment: @Rob that was the problem. If you'd post that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was that the account was locked.
Message found in /var/log/secure:
User  not allowed because account is locked
Solution: give the user a new password.

Comment: I fixed it by changing password field in `/etc/shadow` for this user from `!` to `*`. After that password authentication is still impossible, but user is not locked anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the exact same problem with PuTTY connecting to an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. It was puzzling because PuTTY's pscp program was working fine with the same key (and the same key worked in PuTTY to connect to another host).

Thanks to the valuable comment from @UtahJarhead, I checked my /var/log/auth.log file and found the following:

```
sshd[17278]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-dss not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes [preauth]
```

It turns out that newer versions of OpenSSH don't accept DSA keys by default. Once I switched from a DSA to an RSA key, it worked fine.

Another approach: this question discusses how to configure the SSH server to accept DSA keys: https://superuser.com/questions/1016989/ssh-dsa-keys-no-longer-work-for-password-less-authentication?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

For me, the solution was opposite [Wojtek Rzepala's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36541/37552): I didn't notice I was still using `authorized_keys2`, which [has been deprecated](http://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=100508718416162&w=2). My ssh setup stopped working at some point, presumably when the server was updated. Renaming `.ssh/authorized_keys2` as `.ssh/authorized_keys` fixed the problem.

D'oh!

Comment: This is also a configuration option in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, although I think I'd rename it like you did.

Answer (score 2):

These steps should help you out. I use this regularly among many 64bit Ubuntu 10.04 machines.

```
[ ! -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ] && ssh-keygen -t rsa;
ssh <username>@<remote_machine> 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh'
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <username>@<remote_machine> 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

you could put this in a script with some prompts and invoke it as

```
script_name username remote_machine
```

Comment: There exists already `ssh-copy-id` which does the last two steps automatically.

Comment: @jofel keep in mind that in many systems ssh-copy-id does not exist.
@Sriharsha after the `mkdir` you should add there `chmod 700 .ssh` too and btw you don't need be so verbose with `~/.ssh`, just `.ssh` is enough since the commands are executed in the home directory anyway

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with ssh. In my case the problem was that I installed hadoop cloudera (from rpm on centos 6) and it created user hdfs with home directory

`/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs` (not standard `/home/hdfs`).

I changed in /etc/passwd `/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs` to `/home/hdfs`, moved home directory to new location and now I can connect with public key authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same problem, and for me the solution was to set `UsePAM` to `no`.  See, even with `PasswordAuthentication` set to `no`, you'll still get `keyboard-interactive`, and in my case my local ssh program kept defaulting to that, for some reason.

Extra background to help anyone with the same situation: I'm connecting from a host running Dropbear to one running OpenSSH.  With `PasswordAuthentication` and `UsePAM` both set `no` on the remote machine, I'll get the following message if I enter `ssh user@server`:

```
ssh: Connection to user@server:22 exited: Disconnect received
```

Providing the identity file with `-i`, everything works as expected.

[There may be a little more information here.](http://osdir.com/ml/org.user-groups.linux.cabal/2006-08/msg00037.html)

Answer (score 1):

My scenario was that I have a NAS server on which I created a `backupbot` user, after the creation of my primary account, which was able to log in to initially create the `backupbot` user. After fiddling with `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and creating the `backupbot` user, `vim` can create, at least on Ubuntu 16.04, and based on your `~/.vimrc` config, a **swap file** left from your vim session's editing of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Check to see if: `/etc/ssh/.sshd_config.swp` exists, and if it does remove it and restart the `sshd` daemon:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/ssh/.sshd_config.swp
$ sudo service sshd restart
```

This magically resolved my issue. I had previously checked all my permissions and even the RSA fingerprints of the public and private keys. This is strange and probably a bug with `sshd`, specifically this version:

> OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is a variant of @Jagadish 's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174482/52236): to [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) the ssh daemon.

It has the significant advantage, that we don't need to stop the sshd, what can result a complete lockout if something goes badly.

First, we find the pid of the main sshd process. Here we can see it by executing a `pstree -pa|less`.

```
  |-sshd,633 -D  <-- THIS IS WHAT WE WANT!
  |   `-sshd,21973   
  |       `-sshd,21996    
  |           `-bash,22000
  |               `-screen,638 -r
```

After knowing, that the pid is 633, we can `strace` it, following its children:

```
strace -p 633 -s 4096 -f -o sux
```

The result will be that *everything* what this sshd, and its child processes have done, will be strace-ed into the file named `sux` in the local directory.

Then reproduce the problem.

It will have a massive list of kernel call log, which is mostly incomprehensible/irrelevant for us, but not everywhere. In my case, the important thing was this:

```
6834  sendto(4, "<38>Jan 15 18:49:21 sshd[6834]: User cica not allowed because account is locked\0", 84, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 84
```

It was meants, that the sshd tried to log the message *User cica not allowed because account is locked* - it only couldn't, because logging is not enough verbose for that. But we already know, the pubkey was rejected because the account was locked.

It is not yet a solution - now we need to google, what means a "locked account" in the case of the sshd. It will be most likely some trivial `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` wizardry, but the important thing is done - the problem isn't a mysterious, but an easily debuggable/googlable one.

Comment: I tried that method. In my case, it was because the ownership of the .ssh folder was wrong. Using sshd -d showed the error, but unfortunately strace didn't catch it. Glad I learned about pstree in your response.

Comment: @WadihM You are right - in this case, strace will only contain that sshd checked the ~/.ssh metadata with an fstat-related syscall. Possibly you would catch also the logging try, possibly not (it depends on, how verbose is sshd without the -d flag). Thanks the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had all permissions right and even when running ssh with -vvv flag I couldn't figure out what was the problem.

So I generated new certificate on **remote host**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

and copied generated keys to local machine and added new public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on remote host

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

Using generated keys from remote host machine connection now works. So if other solutions fail this is another thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when connecting from Raspbian8 to Fedora34.

The debug error I received was:

```bsh
userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

The solution was to append ***ssh-rsa*** to the value of PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms in

```yaml
/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config
```

and restart the service

> thanks to Dave @ https://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Fedora/34/SSH+Pubkey+doesn%27t+work for this solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried to log into a colleague's account without password, by pasting id_rsa.pub into her authorized_keys file. I got the permissions of all relevant files right, but still couldn't succeed with password-less login.

It turns out since I created the authorized_keys file with root permission, I had to chown and chgrp to the ones that match her profile.

```
sudo chown ${username} -R /home/${username}/.ssh
sudo chgrp ${groupname} -R /home/${groupname}/.ssh
```

It was easy to spot this mistake when you use the triple verbose mode ssh -vvv.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `id_rsa` authentication appears to be deprecated and is not utilized by default in SSH. Switching to `ed25519` resolved my problem.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 username@remote
```