# Server does not accept public key for ssh login without password

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication)

I have ssh access to two sever. One old one and one new one. For the old one I use the tutorial [SSH login without password](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) to login without typing the password every time.

For the new machine I followed the tutorial again, but this time it is not working. I looked at the debug output from ssh (`-v` option) and it seems to me that the new server does not `accept` my public key. But I checked and bot `authorized_keys` are the same, I even used `md5sum`.

What could be the problem and how could I fix this?

**Debug output for old server where it does work (snippet):**

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/NICK/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
```

**Debug output for new server where it does not work (snippet):**

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/NICK/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/NICK/.ssh/id_dsa
```

[**UPDATE] Ownership of authorized_keys on remote**

```
NICK@server-new:~/.ssh$ ls -l
total 4
-rwx------ 1 NICK NICK 404 2012-08-08 16:11 authorized_keys
```

---

**Complete debug output for the not working server:**

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/NICK/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/NICK/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for foo2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to foo-serv2.cs.bar.it [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/NICK/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/NICK/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/NICK/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/NICK/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/NICK/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/NICK/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA XXX
debug1: Host 'foo-serv2.cs.bar.it' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/NICK/.ssh/known_hosts:34
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/NICK/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/NICK/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/NICK/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the ownership and mode of your ~/.ssh directory on the remote side is correct?  It should be owned by you, and have 0700 permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the permissions, but the error stayed the same.

Comment: Four-oh-four error: -rwx------ 1 NICK NICK **404** 2012-08-08 16:11 authorized_keys

Comment: 404 is the file size, or?

Comment: Keep in mind, I meant the permissions on the **DIRECTORY** and not the **FILES** in ~/.ssh.  I meant you were to run `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`.

Comment: Thanks @jsbillings, that was the solution! If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: If you would have run `sshd` in debug-mode you would have seen the problem much faster...

Comment: @Gilles, thanks, I did not find this question while searching. I flagged my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Did you make sure that the ownership and mode of your ~/.ssh directory on the remote side is correct? It should be owned by you, and have 0700 permissions, i.e. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`. Also `chmod go-w ~` as this is checked also - because anyone with write permission on your home directory can change the permissions of the .ssh directory.

Comment: Apparently the home directory must be set to `700` as well (or less permissive than `777`, anyway).

Comment: Yes, 777 is a really bad mode to have your homedir.  That means ANYONE on the system could add/remove/modify files in your homedir (at least, if it's just unix permissions restricting access)

Comment: In my case, my home directory was 775 and I saw this problem. Changing it to 755 fixed it for me.

Comment: 755 of home directory works well for me.

Comment: @Tgr thank you good sir for resolving my vexing problem

Comment: Set the permission of the home directory as 740 in the server works for me.

Comment: @sbillings, you saved my life!

Comment: dis worked for me :thumbsup:

Answer (score 6):

Compare the sshd configuration files (mine's at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) on the old and new server - is something set up differently on the new one, for example does the `AuthorizedKeysFile` option on the new one point to some other file (I believe some SSH installations nowadays call the file `authorized_keys2`)?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I checked the files, but there were both identical.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your sshd service. Something like `service sshd restart` depending on OS