# rsync to remote server without password

Tags: ssh, rsync

I seem to be having a little issue with connecting to a remote server, to `rsync` my backups

what i have done so far

run    `ssh-keygen`
created public and private key

run    `ssh-copy-id -i my.key.pub 100.0.0.01`

it all connected ok, i even went to remote server and checked
    `.ssh/authorized_key` and confirmed the key was there

but when i run `ssh 100.0.0.01` it still asks for a password, plus when i run a `cron` job to `rsync` it fails with permission denied.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why it wont connect?

Comment: If you're running SElinux, you may need to run `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh`

Comment: Are you certain you're running `ssh` with the correct user name for the remote server?

Comment: hi , yes, when i access through ssh i can connect, but it keeps asking me for the pasword, when i apply the password i can conect

Comment: Your use of `my.key.pub` on `ssh-copy-id` suggests you named your privatekey file `my.key` not the `ssh-keygen` default `.ssh/id_rsa` (or `dsa` or whatever). If so, that file won't be used. You must either (1) put the file in `.ssh` with the default name; (2) specify `-i my.key` on `ssh` and `-e 'ssh -i my.key'` on `rsync`, plus path if not in the same dir; or (3) create or edit `.ssh/config` to specify it. And in all cases it must be accessible only by your id. @roaima #269452 is for a `ppk` file generated by PuTTY, clearly not the case for this Q.

Comment: @dave_Thompson_085 the permissions aspect is potentially equally relevant, although I like your suggested diagnosis here

Comment: hi, i carried out your suggestions, and it worked, i changed the file name to default id_rca.pub, and it connected fine, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @roaima #269452 contains nothing about permissions, although #36540 (linked in comment by DanGetz on answer) does.

Answer (score 2):

- Check permissions of `~/.ssh` folder and its content in **client** and **server** machine.
- Check `/etc/ssh/ssd_config` in the **server** to ensure that `RSAAuthentication`, `PubkeyAuthentication` and `UsePAM` options aren't disabled, as they are enabled by default with `yes`.
- If you entered a passphrase while generating your client key, then you may try `ssh-agent` & `ssh-add` to achieve password-less connections in your session.
- Check the contents of `/var/log/auth.log` on the **server** to find the issue why key authentication is skipped at all.

Comment: Don't just check the permissions of `~/.ssh`, check all the directories above `~/.ssh` all the way up to `/`, and the permissions of the files in it.

Comment: all permissions are set correctly, root root

Comment: i didnt use a pass phrase

Comment: What do you see in /var/log/auth.log

Comment: /var/log/auth.log is empty on both client and server

Comment: @user2513528 just being owned by `root` doesn't mean the permissions are correct; are you sure you checked that permissions aren't *too permissive*? See [this answer to another question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36687/66663)

Comment: Check your permissions on /var/log/auth.log. Should look something like: -rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 210149 Nov 17 11:42 /var/log/auth.log. If needed restart syslog: /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart. Check as well the system logging configuration file: /etc/syslog.conf

Answer (score 0):

Three things to think about:

1) Is the remote host configured to allow key authentication? (See `man sshd_config` AuthenticationMethods and PubkeyAuthentication)

2) Is the cron job scheduled to run under the right user context ( root vs. other user )

3) Do you have permission on the remote host to the target directory.

Answer (score -3):

```
cd
ssh-keygen 
cp .ssh/id_rsa.pub .ssh/authorized-keys
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub 100.0.0.1
```

Comment: -1 for two reasons. (a) there's no explanation of what this does or what you intend it to do, (b) the asker explained they'd already done this but it hadn't worked for them.

Comment: This is a response to the question's title, not the question itself.