# Being Prompted for Password After Already Registered Public Key On server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

NOTE: This is **not** a duplicate to the popular question.
[Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication)

I had an original post but I did not get much answers helping me. I will try and explain my 3 day problem in thorough detail.

**How I added the id_rsa.pub ssh key into my Ubuntu server:**

What I did was I created it through my normal windows 10 computer through a git scm terminal (can be found here https://git-for-windows.github.io/). I had to use git because a normal cmd prompt in windows 10 would not work. I generated it through ssh-keygen which generated 2 keys for me, one id_rsa and one id_rsa.pub.

After that I went on my putty terminal, logged into my remote server and created a .ssh directory in my /home/superjohnny folder (my sudo user) and I made a folder within the .ssh folder called authorized_keys. I copied and pasted my id_rsa.pub key into the authorized_keys folder and then later added 600 permissions on it by doing chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys.

Once I did that I went into my /etc/ssh/sshd_config and added the following into my config settings:

```
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

All these lines are also uncommented. I then did sudo service ssh restart and then I still get a password prompt when trying to log in. This has been going on for a week

**The methods I have tried:**
I have used both threads that were discussed above to try and get an answer and I have also used my google search extensively. Here are the methods that I have used.

**1. Putting the key on one line**
I have tried using in the git scm terminal on my computer the following command:

```
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | awk '{print}' ORS=' '
```

The command above supposedly doesn't do anything because the key was already on one line when I copied it, it's just that the terminal couldn't fit the key. Here is the thread I have used to find that command.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818651/how-to-display-output-on-single-line

2. **Using the wc command:**
   Using this command:

   ```
   wc ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

   I have gotten an output of:

   ```
     1   3 398 /home/superjohnny/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
3. **Checking if my home directory is encrypted:**
   I have used the following command:

   ```
   ls -A /home/superjohnny
   ```

   and I have gotten an output of:

   ```
   .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .profile  .ssh  .viminfo
   ```

   There was no .encrypted folder to be found.
4. **Going on debugging mode to check for extra information:**
   While on a session I did the following command:

   ```
   ssh -v superjohnny@myip
   ```

and got this as a result:

```
    debug1: Found key in /home/superjohnny/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/superjohnny/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/superjohnny/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/superjohnny/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/superjohnny/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

This must be a hint to something but looking through the web for awhile I couldn't find much about this problem, only found a thread about it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54670/passwordless-ssh-not-working
And this thead just tells me to recreate the key file which I have done **numerous** times

5. **Using grep command:**
   Using the following command:

   ```
   grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | wc -l
   ```

   I get a output of:

   ```
   1
   ```
6. **Checking logs messages:**
   Using the following command:

   ```
   sudo vi /var/log/auth.log
   ```

   I have received a lot of errors all on the same day, the same exact error but I will only post a bit of it:

   ```
    Apr 25 04:14:01 ramnode CRON[977]: pam_unix(cron:session): session    closed for user root
   Apr 25 04:54:01 ramnode CRON[1076]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
   ```

   I have not received any other messages in any other days other than April 25th.
7. **Going on debugging mode with sshd:**

Doing

```
    /usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

gives me an output of:

```
    debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
    debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': Permission denied
    Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key': Permission denied
    Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': Permission denied
    Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
    debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key': Permission denied
    Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
    debug1: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted
    debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
    debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
```

However adding sudo in front of the command likeso:

```
    sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

gives me an output of:

```
    debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
    debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
    debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
    debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
    debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
    debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
    debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA
    debug1: private host key: #3 type 4 ED25519
    debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
    debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
    Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from -800 to -1000
```

8. **Trying to see if home directory permissions had to be smaller:**
   I tried to change the home directory permissions because I thought that the permissions might not allowed for the .ssh directory to work. I used the following command:

   ```
   chmod 755 ~/
   ```

   but that did nothing at all when I restarted my terminal with sudo service ssh restart and then when I logged back into another terminal it still prompted me with a password.
9. **Trying to disable Password** 
   I have tried to disable the password and not logging out of my secession so I can change it if it doesn't work. I did this by going into the

   ```
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```

   but when I went on to a new terminal screen I get the following error:

   ```
   Disconnected: No supported authentication methods avaliable(server sent: publickey
   ```

The /var/log/auth.log messages that I had when trying to log in with password disabled so the system would try and use ssh keys was this:

```
    May  1 09:02:00 ramnode sshd[16905]: error: Received disconnect from 64.121.77.168: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
    May  1 09:02:13 ramnode sudo: superjohnny : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/superjohnny ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/vi /var/log/auth.log
    May  1 09:02:13 ramnode sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by superjohnny(uid=0)
```

Comment: THERE IS NO REASON TO SHOUT.  We have **bold** and *italics* for emphasis.

Comment: Ok, I'll change it, sorry it's been a rough 3 days.

Comment: It is still most likely that your `.authorizedkeys` file is not correct. Don't you have the command `ssh-copy-id` on your client (windows) box to copy the id? Have you logged into the server (with password) and ran `wc ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (output should be 1)?

Comment: And if you don't have `ssh-copy-id`, you can use `scp id_rsa.pub user@server:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (assuming you don't already have other public ids in there)

Comment: Ok, I will delete my authorized key file and try again with your method

Comment: You have at least wrong permissions on `.ssh/authorized_keys` **file** and `.ssh` folder. It should be `0600` and `0700` respectively. Also checking the verbose log of server, will give you the hint what is wrong.

Comment: 600 on the .ssh and 700 on authorized keys?

Comment: @JohnnyInno1 No 700 on `.ssh` (as that is a directory) and 600 on the `authorized_keys` file in that directory

Comment: Ok, it I've added those permissions and it still doesn't work,  I have also tried your method @Anthon but it says it doesn't exist even though I literally have the files... the output error is in my post sorry.

Comment: That the copy doesn't work is because you missed the `~` which indicates your home directory. The output from `wc` looks ok though (one line, three words). You can try to look at `/var/log/messages` on the server to see if it says something useful. Or start `ssh -v superjohnny@myip` for extra debugging

Comment: After my debugging I realized that "supposebly" every line in my etc/ssh/ssh_config  has an error.. how do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like your /etc/ssh/ssh_config was overwritten with something else. Can you show its contents (the first 10 lines)?

Comment: You are correct that your question is not a duplicate.  You are wrong about the reason.  A dupe is still a dupe if the underlying problem is the same, even if the Linux distro is different and even if the older question is for FreeBSD or OS X or AIX or Solaris or some other non-Linux unix.  In other words, the fact that you're on Ubuntu and the other question is on Centos doesn't automatically prevent your question from being a duplicate.

Comment: Ok I have changed that, I also don't have errors now but when going on degugging mode my server just skips the passwords...

Comment: you really need to be a lot clearer about what you are trying to do and what your problem is.  what is this `git bash` you keep talking about?  sounds like nonsensical misunderstanding to me.  what are you actually trying to do?  ssh from a windows box using putty to an ubuntu box?  ssh from the ubuntu box to somewhere else?  what exactly does `created a file which was pretty much id_rsa.pub by using the touch command` mean?  `touch` can't create key files, that's a job for `ssh-keygen` (on ubuntu) or `puttgen` (on windows).  and forget that nonsense about using awk or anything to {cont}

Comment: {cont} put it all on one line - it **is** already on one line, it just takes a lot more more than one 80-column terminal line to display.  As for your claim that `There is literally nothing i am doing wrong`, you are absolutely wrong about that.

Comment: Alright, I have changed it, sorry for the lack of knowledge in linux.

Comment: you mentioned changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so i guess that means you have root access on the ubuntu server.  if so, a) did you restart `sshd` after changing its config? and b) what does `/var/log/auth.log` show when you try to log in?   BTW, given your description of how you created `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` it is possible you messed it up somehow - try `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | wc -l`.  That will count the number of non-empty lines in the file, which should equal the number of keys - so if you've only ever added one key to it, the result should be `1`.

Comment: Using sudo service ssh restart doesn't appear to do anything, when I do ~var/log/auth.log it says permission denied. Typing in the command `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | wc -l` gives me a result of 1.

Comment: I've literally been just rechecking everything from my sshd config to and doing grep over and over again, I have also checked my var log, it just says that this: `Apr 25 04:54:01 ramnode CRON[1076]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory`. I have done literally everything, I have looked everywhere for the answer and I find that they jsut give the same answers, no one has really had an ssh key problem as serious as mine...

Comment: I have tried @Anthon's method again, the wc command now gives me another output that is in my post.

Comment: Have you tried putting the remote sshd into debug mode ? It may have a reason for denying the key auth.

Comment: What do you mean by "do ~var/log/auth.log"? `/var/log/auth.log` is a log file that you are supposed to look in, with e.g. `sudo less /var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: @Henrik Sorry for not being so specific, I meant I used a text editor to look at it using `sudo vi /var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, My outputs for ssh debug mode are in the post, I don't really know how would I specifically debug sshd. If you have the command for it that would be nice.

Comment: Did you not read through http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36540/117549 ?

Comment: You're saying you get "permission denied" when using `sudo vi`? Is there SELinux or some other (please tell us which, if there is) additional security features enabled on the server?

Comment: @Henrick that was before when I did `~var/log/auth.log`, the actual syntax of it is `var/log/auth.log` which I was not doing. If you read the thread you can see the output of what I get when using `sudo vi var/log/auth.log'.There is no other secutrity feature on my server unless you count disabling root login as one in my sshd_config

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I read part of it and I found out an error message in it, it method 6 in the post

Comment: @JeffSchaller I dug about it more and I found out the reason it was saying permission denied for all the keys was because I was not putting sudo in front of the command so now I use it like this `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd`.

Comment: The point of debug sshd was to gather the logs when you try to log in with a key. What happened?

Comment: It printed out the above on method 7.

Comment: I still don't see any sshd logs from your key-based authentication attempt.

Comment: I'm sorry, isn't doing `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` going into debugging mode on sshd? All my logs that I have are above on method 7 from debugging mode on sshd, sorry if I am not getting what you are saying.

Comment: I have tried to force my server to use key based authentication by disabling passwords in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, is this what you were asking Jeff? The following error message I got from it is in the above post.

Comment: Your sshd output is only of sshd's startup; what does sshd say when you then try to log in?

Comment: I think I get what your saying, I posted a `/var/log/auth.log` message with password disabled to see if it would say anything about ssh keys, I updated method 8 with the var logs of trying to go in by "forcing" it to use ssh keys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39146/discussion-between-johnnyinno1-and-jeff-schaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of a very good friend who was very patient with my problem. The problem was that the putty client was not set up to accept my key, I had the authorized key files and all the permissions right it's just that this one little problem was not noticed until now.

In my putty client I did not put in a private key into my secession and I originally had thought that the remote server would just look into my files and check to see if the key was there. I was wrong and my friend had told me that this would be a huge security risk and said that the private key had to be put into putty likeso:

[image]

Thank you guys for also helping too, I learned a lot along the way with this problem.