# What can go wrong if we disable selinux

Tags: linux, ssh, selinux

We inherited a bunch of used servers from another team.  Some of them have SELinux enabled on it, some do not.  Because of SELinux, we are having trouble setting up passwordless ssh, our webserver, etc.  We found a work around on [this stackexchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication/36687#36687), which is to run:

```
restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh
```

However, since we don't need SELinux running for what we do, it might be easier to turn it off than for us to remember to have everyone run the above cmd on whatever dir needs permissions.

Can we turn SELinux off w/o any repercussions down the road or is it better to just re-image the server?  One thing to note; our IT group is really busy so re-imaging a server is not high on their list unless it's absolutely necessary (need a very good business case)...or someone bribes their boss with a bottle of scotch or whiskey.

UPDATE: Thanks for everyone's suggestion and advice.  These servers are all going to be used as internal dev servers.  There isn't going to be any outside access to these machines so security isn't a high concern to us.  Our current servers that we are using all (to the best of my knowledge) do not have SELinux enabled.  Some of the ones my manager just acquired do and those are the ones we're looking at disabling so everything in our cluster is uniform.

Comment: I answered a similar question on Android.se: [How dangerous is the fact that SELinux is in “Permissive” mode? What should I be wary of?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/152329/107603). The main difference between "Permissive" mode and disabling SELinux is that you will not get AVC log messages anymore and that SELinux will not keep files label up-to-date so you will need to relabel your files before enabling it again.

Comment: "What could possibly go wrong?"

Comment: @scai That's actually a good question. As [Sato Katsura](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300144/what-can-go-wrong-if-we-disable-selinux/300148?noredirect=1#comment528610_300147) points out, SELinux is hard to use effectively. A false sense of security is harmful to security.

Answer (score 16):

SELinux is a *security feature* of the operating system.  It is designed to help protect some parts of the server from other parts.

For example, if you run a web server and have some "vulnerable" code that allows for an attacker to run arbitrary commands then SELinux can help mitigate this, by preventing your web server from accessing files it's not allowed to see.

Now you *can* disable SELinux and it shouldn't break anything.  The server will keep on working as normal.

But you will have disabled one of the security features.

Comment: SELinux works well only when configured properly.  However, SELinux is so complicated that nobody has the time and / or knowledge to configure it properly, and thus it ends up either disabled, or as a perpetual pain in the rear for the admin.  Yet you guys keep investing faith in it as a _security_ feature.

Comment: I agree that selinux is a PITA to administer, yet it's still fair and entirely accurate to call it a security feature.  for those who want or **need** to invest the time in learning and administering it (not me), it's invaluable - e.g. sysadmins for a large, high-profile web site aka an attractive target for script kiddies around the world.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Simply because it's hard to configure or difficult to understand doesn't justify disabling a security mechanism. Provided that this security mechanism is actually needed which is not always easy to decide.

Comment: @scai I didn't say it should (or shouldn't) be disabled.  What I'm saying is, the underlying model of SELinux is flawed. Some people [argue](https://www.google.com/search?q=pledge+de+raadt) that __all__ security mechanisms that can be disabled are flawed.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes, that's why having passwords is completely and utterly pointless because they can be disabled (e.g. with pam or nss or just by having a blank password).  BTW, i never claimed that you said selinux should be disabled.  i was just disputing your assertion that it's not a real security feature.

Comment: @cas You didn't. @ scai did.

Answer (score 9):

There are varying views of SELinux.  In many cases, some applications do not play well with SELinux so that this decision is moot (Oracle is one example).
Generally, SELinux is a protecting mechanism to put yet another obstacle in the way of a bad guy wanting to subvert your system.

In my previous roles as Systems Administrator at large companies ... I have generally disabled SELinux.  I did not have the time to track down all the SELinux errors on all the systems being used by users, developers, and managers.

Before disabling things, you might want to start by relabeling the files on the system back to what they should be.  The easiest method I have found is entering the command:

```
 # /sbin/fixfiles onboot
```

OR

```
 # touch /.autorelabel
```

Then, reboot, and wait as it will take about the same amount of time for the system to verify and reset errant SELinux labels in the system.  After that you might be ok as it fixes and corrects non-conforming SELinux labels which may have been modified prior to your attempting administration of the server.

However, if it doesn't, the system will not be harmed by NOT having SELinux in enforcing mode.  It's just an extra layer of protection.

Comment: moot, not mute. But perfectly correct; not all systems need selinux.

Comment: +1 for advising to try to globally relabel the files before disabling SELinux as a fallback. SELinux is meant to prevent unexpected software and users behavior. On systems where there is no well-defined expected behavior, SELinux may indeed cause more harm than good (OS-provided policies try to be as general as possible, but sometimes this is not enough).

Comment: Thank you! `/sbin/fixfiles onboot` worked for me on CentOS, not so with `touch /.autorelabel`.  Running `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log` shows 0 alerts now.  @mdpc What's the difference between those two commands?

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, disabling mandatory access control(MAC) mechanisms like **SELinux** is not a good idea and may put you at a security-disadvantage if a bad guy successfully circumvent name-based access controls, implemented by Discretionary Access Control(DAC).

Were it me, I would do something like

```
semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t ~/.ssh # Adding the policy
restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh # Applying the policy
```

to be extra sure about the *type-label* assigned recursively from `~/.ssh`

Comment: It's stylised "SELinux". Linux is not an acronym, and the "SE" part is an initialism.

Comment: @Rhymoid : That's a good note indeed.. In fact what I wrote was accidental.

Comment: It's not a good idea.... *if the only thing you care about is security*. But nobody uses a computer just so they can say "look how secure it is!"; they want to actually get stuff done!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you shouldn't disable SELinux. There are tools that might help you understand what gone wrong. My favorite is sealert
example usage:

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

OFC you can always set SELinux in permissive mode for debug, but keeping SELinux disabled or permissive is taught as serious security flaw by Red Hat.