# Can't login via ssh using public key

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to my Ubuntu server using ssh and a public key. I have disabled the connection from remote using a password, so I can only login using a key.

There are two users on my server. When I connect using the pubkey for the first user, everything goes fine. Connection is made, key is checked, I get logged in  with no issues.

But when I try to log in as the secondary user, then the connection is refused. These were my steps. Suppose my secondary username is `tom`.

1. I created a new pair of keys on my system using `ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519 -f id_tom -C "tom"`
2. copied the public key into the clipboard
3. once on the server as `tom`, I made a new `.ssh` directory within `home` and created new `authorized_keys` file, changing the permissions file to `600` and pasted the public key
4. I appended the following lines to `~/.ssh/config` on my local machine:

   ```
   Host tom_server
   HostName 687.22.14.4 
   User tom
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/path/to/id_tom
   IdentitiesOnly yes
   ```

Looking at the debug log, I can say that ssh correctly tries to authenticate as `tom` and the right key is passed to the server. So what could be the issue here? What am I overlooking?

**Update**: I have tried the solutions posted in [Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication) and nothing so far has worked.

Comment: did you name the file `authorization_keys`, or `authorized_keys`? What are the permissions of `~` and `~/.ssh`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication)

Comment: @JeffSchaller you are right, I made a typo in the question, which I have edited now. I'm not getting the chance to put in a password, because I disabled it. Permissions for `~` are set to `755` and for `.ssh` are set to `700`.

Comment: Just to clarify (you didn't make it explicit), you created .ssh and authorized_keys on the *server*, not locally, right?

Comment: @JeffSchaller right!

Comment: The server sshd logs may be helpful; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55481/117549

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include these clarifications please? Also clarify that you've checked all of the issues mentioned in the answer to the duplicate post. Finally, does the user who can connect have an `authorized_keys2` file by any chance? I admit I don't know why, but I;ve seen some systems use `authorized_keys2` instead of `authorized_keys`.

Comment: @terdon nope, just `authorized_keys`.

Comment: In the debug log, what happens when the correct key is tried?  Does the server respond with any message or does it drop through to the next authentication mechanism/key? ... do you get `debug1: Offering public key tom` ... followed by `debug2: we sent a publickey packet`

Comment: @RubberStamp when I try to connect with my primary user `sshd` finds the matching key in `authorized_keys` and logs me in. And yes if I launch `ssh -vvv tom_server` I get `debug 1: Offering public key...` and later `debug 2: we sent a publickey packet...`

Comment: The prior similar comment had an error... of course, you will want to search the auth log for your connecting ip and not your server ip... sorry about that... So: on the server side... does this give any clues `cat /var/log/auth.log |grep "sshd.*your.host.ip.addr"`

Comment: @RubberStamp unfortunately no useful information is listed "received/disconnect/accepted"...

Comment: Is the content of `auth.log` the same for the user that works and the user that doesn't work ?  ... there should be a bunch of failures in the auth log for the user that doesn't work... these should all have the suffix `[preauth]` ... unless sshd logging is turned off for some reason... are you running SELinux on your server? ... You question lacks specific details which are necessary to debug your setup.  The precise lines of the log files are informative both in complete content and order.  >"received/disconnect/accepted" is not helpful.