# Repeated prompts for SSH private key password in single session

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, ssh-agent, ssh-config

I have a private SSH key on a shared development server, which is secured with a password.

**Even after loading it into `ssh-agent`, I get re-prompted for the private key password**

For some reason, even after I `ssh-add` the private key, and correctly respond to the password prompt, I am subsequently prompted for the same private key password *again*, when I `git pull` in a git clone which uses the same identity file on the same hostname.

I load my SSH settings after login, this way:

```
➜  ~ cat ~/init_ssh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I run the script and correctly answer the password prompt:

```
➜  ~ ~/init_ssh
Agent pid 11612
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

I then run `git pull` or `git push` in a specific repository clone, and *every single time* I have to re-enter my SSH password:

```
➜  repository_clone git:(master) git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Already up-to-date.
➜  repository_clone git:(master) git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Already up-to-date.
```

**The hostname has an `IdentityFile` configured in `~/.ssh/config`**

It so happens that I have the `IdentityFile` for `github.com` explicitly set to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
➜  repository_clone git:(master) cat ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If I remove the above SSH config entry, I still have the same problem with perpetual password re-prompt.

**File permissions are correct**

I have confirmed, meanwhile, that all of the permissions on `~` and `~/.ssh` directories and the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file are what they should be, according to [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36687/153722):

```
➜  ~ ls -la ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw-------  1 username username 3326 Sep 21 16:53 /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa

/home/username:
total 220
drwxr-xr-x  13 username username  4096 Sep 27 17:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root     root      4096 Sep 21 16:09 ..
# [...]

/home/username/.ssh:
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  2 username username 4096 Sep 27 17:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 username username 4096 Sep 27 17:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 username username  745 Sep 21 16:43 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 username username  455 Sep 27 17:07 config
-rw-------  1 username username 3326 Sep 21 16:53 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 username username  744 Sep 21 16:53 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 username username 3794 Sep 26 16:28 known_hosts
```

I'm totally stumped! Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agent you start is only available to the `~/init_ssh` script, which immediately exits after it loads the key.

Use `source ~/init_ssh` or place `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in your `.profile` or equivalent file.

After you load the agent, you should have `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` point so a socket.