# Same pubkey allows access on one user, but not another

Tags: centos, ssh

So I have a centos 7 server with 2 users.

User1 has the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file with proper permissions and with externaluser's public key in it.

User2 has the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file with proper permissions and with the same externaluser's public key in it.

Externaluser can ssh to User1 with no problems, however, he gets `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)` error when trying to ssh to User2.

Why does this happen? It's literally the same public key, properly pasted into the `authorized_keys` file of each user, using the same method.

Comment: Please, try `ssh -v` for more detailed information about what's happening and add it to your question.

Comment: Check the owner and permissions on `.ssh` and on `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Please check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication and show the results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you RalfFriedl for your [useful comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474281#comment866409_474281), the problem was the `.ssh` folder permissions.

> Check the owner and permissions on `.ssh` and on `authorized_keys`.