# Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root

Tags: ssh, permissions, sshd, key-authentication

I'm trying to SSH into my remote VPS with Debian onboard. Running sshd in debug mode, I found that:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root
```

I tried setting permissions as I found in Google:

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But it still refuses auth with pubkey and asks for password, with the same message in debug. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: to round out the error-checking, what is the ownership of /root? `ls -ld /root`

Comment: Additionally, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36687/117549, your home directory (`/root` here) must only be readable to you, so `go-w` may not be enough.

Comment: Re-run your chmod commands referencing /root/ explicitly.  It is not clear from your context what `~/` is.  Do `chmod go-w /root/`, etc.  And as @JeffSchaller requests, edit your post to add the output of `ls -ld /root` and `ls -ld /root/.ssh`

Comment: It works, but ssh service display log: `ssh.service: Found left-over process 1704 (sshd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.` and `This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.`

Answer (score 17):

Well, I should really thank @jeff-schaller, it was broken ownership of folder. I've done

```
chown root /root
chown root /root/.ssh
```

And from there it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Comment: I had to use both: </br>
<pre>
chown root /root
chown root /root/.ssh

And then:
`chmod go-w ~/`
`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

It worked after that.