# scripted ssh should not ask for a password if public key authentication fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ssh, openssh

Here is my use case: I have a script that lists through hundreds of servers and tests whether or not they allow logins using `public key authentication` using a specific `private key` (in the ssh client's `.ssh` directory). Some of these servers were misconfigured, and I do not have control over the SSH service on any of these servers.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q $x exit
returncode=$?
```

So this works so far for most servers (i.e., returns a `non-zero` return code when a server is unreachable, and `0` when the server can be logged-in to), until some troublesome server fails due to some SSH misconfiguration (ex. `~/.ssh` on the remote server has an incorrect permission. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication) is a related thread describing what can be done in such case.

But i don't want to fix the remote servers. I just want SSH to fail and exit with a `non-zero` return code if `SSH key authentication` fails.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` option

Comment: The title suggests that `ssh` (in some circumstances?) asks for password despite `PasswordAuthentication=no` and this is the problem. The question body suggests that `ssh` in some circumstances fails (returns non-zero exit status) despite the fact the key matches, and this is the problem. In the latter case no password is involved at all. Or do I get it wrong? For now I'm confused, I don't know which problem is the problem. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Take a look at Ansible, seems perfect for this task

Comment: There IS a -o batchmode=yes option to avoid ssh asking anything. (Esther confirming signature or asking password)

Comment: @Archemar please post as an answer, it looks useful and would be a more decent approach IMO as it would not involve another command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggestion,

`ssh` has a `-o  batchmode=yes` option that will prevent any interaction.

- no password asked
- no confirmation for foreign signature

This will result in error code if no connection is make.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `timeout` in addition to limit `ssh`'s runtime:

`timeout 10 ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q $x exit
returncode=$?`

or

`timeout --preserve-status 10 ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q $x exit
returncode=$?`

Be sure to choose a good timeout. 2 seconds `ConnectTimeout` plus 8 seconds for running `exit` sould be enough; even on high load.

Comment: great, works perfectly.