# How to view Graphical view of Application using ssh

Tags: ssh, rhel, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to forward X over SSH from Ubuntu machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine)

Is it possible that I can view the GUI of application when I pass some command to Redhat linux Server using ssh. Like when I pass command Firefox it launches the Firefox and I can see GUI Firefox.

Note :: I have not installed vnc server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes compression might be useful in X over ssh sessions.

```
ssh -X -C -oCompressionLevel=9 me@my.server.local mandelbulber
```

Here's how I launch mandelbulber on my desktop PC but utilizing my server performance to calculate fractals.

Answer (score 1):

add -X cli option to ssh client, like that:

```
ssh -X user@server
```

then you will be able to launch GUI apps on your server.