# With SSH X11 forwarding (`ssh -X`), get `Can't open display` trying to run X applications

Tags: ssh, rhel, x11

I'm able to login to the server using:

```
ssh -X Hostip
```

but when I run the command `xclock` it gives me this error:

```
Error: Can't open display: localhost:11.0
```

I checked my display value using:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

and the result is:

```
localhost:11.0
```

And X11 forwarding is set to YES in sshd_config file:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Do you have any advice what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `-Y` instead of `-X`?

Comment: Also, make sure you understand the implications of using `-Y` instead of `-X`. You may also want to look at `xhost`.

Comment: For RedHat/CentOS 7 (at least), you need the xorg-x11-xauth package, as per my answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138936/why-wont-x11-display-work-through-ssh-login/212952#212952

Answer (score 24):

Use `-Y`. From the man page on ssh:

> -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

If you're still having problems though, you can try [setting `$DISPLAY` to your local box's IP](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/xhost-cannot-open-display/):

```
$ export DISPLAY='<ip_address>:11.0'
```

It may work to set it as

```
$ export DISPLAY='127.0.0.1:11.0'
```

People seem to have this problem commonly when [ssh'ing from Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/a/443175/195019). You may also want to set

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

in this case as well.

Comment: Using XQuartz I was unable to use the -Y flag.

"X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication."

Comment: even after trying your other suggestions, I'm unable to open a display.

Comment: Neither one of these worked for me either. I needed to install XWindow support in my Centos 7 server (minimal) with: yum groupinstall "X Window System" -y

Comment: @MarkEdington this is because RedHat/CentOS require the xorg-x11-xauth package, as per my answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138936/why-wont-x11-display-work-through-ssh-login/212952#212952

Answer (score 10):

this worked for me:

Change

```
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

to

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Comment: Thanks, Don.  that worked for me also.  I gave you an upvote.  I believe the problem interfering with the default was that the specific machine is xhost enabled.

Comment: on guest? host? which configuration file? thx to complete your answer

Comment: I made it to work by dropping the settings to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: **focal**: Bad configuration option: x11uselocalhost

Answer (score 9):

*Credit to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/61349 for their diagnostic instructions.*

Ensure you're ssh client is requesting X11 Forwarding with the **-v** flag

```
ssh example.com -X -v
```

And look for thespecific message:

> ```
> debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
> ```

Another telltail problem sign is the lack of the `DISPLAY` environment variable beign set for you. If its blank/unset, there is something wrong. At least according to [the same post credited above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/61349), these variables are set for you automatically.

---

I was using an SSH Control Master my ssh connections like so:

```
Host <hostname>
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/control/%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 10m
```

My earlier ssh connection did not request X11Firwarding, therefore future `ssh` call's options weren't being used. So for me,

**ssh `-X` was just being ignored altogether**

If you aren't seeing "Requesting X11 Forwarding", but you do see the muxer reusing sessions;

> ```
> debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
> debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 10
> ```

Then you need to exit your current ControlMaster for that connection and reconnect with the -X/-Y flag.

To Stop your ControlMaster

> `ssh -O check <hostname>`
>
> ```
> Master running (pid=2758)
> ```
>
> (This will exit all active connections using the ControlMaster)
>
> `ssh -O exit <hostname>`
>
> ```
> Exit request sent.
> ```

Comment: what *should* I do if I see `debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing` then?

Answer (score 5):

What fixed this for me is simply installing xauth, once done it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

When trying to forward to XQuartz on macOS, I fixed the issue by running the `ssh` command (`ssh -Y` in my case) from the XQuartz terminal (opened by right-clicking the XQuartz icon in the dock and clicking Applications > Terminal).

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: The only way that worked for me too (instead of using iterm2). So this means it's a problem on the client (MacOS).

Answer (score 0):

Problem got fixed by installing "x11-server-utils" and reloading both sshd and my ssh session.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem - i was working on a remote server where i had to work with interactive plots and none of the above mentioned solutions worked for me.

I was using Ubuntu bash on Windows 10 and in the end installing Xming software (http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) on Windows. There might be some configurations needed but I was finally able to work with plots on remote server. Just install and launch it (you can see its icon on the bottom tray), and run your graphical application again on the remote server (using the ssh session). Hope it helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).