# control keyboard input on GUI over SSH

Tags: debian, ssh

i am searching for a solution how to echo a keydown over SSH to a running GUI (based on debian).

like VNC or Teamviewer but only command line based.

Comment: Explain more. What have you tried. What is the recipient of the keydown. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why a keydown to a GUI, is there something you cannot do from the commandline?

Comment: for example: openoffice impress with an ppt file is running and to start it, normaly you can press the "F5" key on the keyboard. but when you only have SSH access, i want to send a 'fake' keypress to the client where impress is running to start the presentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) to find the window and send a key event. Example, assuming 'OpenOffice Impress' is in the titlebar of that application, and that it is running on `$DISPLAY :0`

```
$ ssh remote-computer
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ xdotool key --window $(xdotool search --name 'OpenOffice Impress')  F5
```

Comment: `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key`

Comment: @aaa error about `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` is not related to xdotool. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely for how to run X applications with remote forwarding