# CentOS as an xterminal

Tags: centos, x11, virtual-machine

I have recently built a new VM on my `CentOS 6.5 system`. The VM has `Ubuntu with ROS`, the robotic operating system on it. I just wanted to experiment with ROS and I've been running some of the tutorials. One of those tutorials has an `X windows based application` in it but I haven't figured out how to get it displayed on the host's desktop display. I'm sure it's easy, and I thought that `vncserver` would do what I needed, but I haven't gotten it to work. I have tested the network connection between the VM and underlying CentOS system and the VMWARE successfully can ping the host. Could anyone point me to an explanation or tell me how to get this working?

Comment: Can you share the tutorial's URL that shows this?

Answer (score 0):

If your host machine (CentOS) has X-windows, you can use `ssh -X` to forward all X11 traffic to your CentOS machine while SSHing into the Ubuntu VM.

For example, if your Ubuntu VM's IP address is 192.168.0.123, and your username on the Ubuntu VM is "fred" you woud use this command from CentOS to connect to the Ubuntu VM:

```
ssh -X fred@192.168.0.123
```

After you connect, just run the command that expects X11 and it should just appear on your CentOS desktop even though it's running on your Ubuntu VM.

There's more to it than just that, so if you run into problems, check out this great answer:
[How to forward X over SSH to run graphics applications remotely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine)