# Start aplication in local desktop from remote SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, remote

I have an issue for which the work around would be to start the application in X instead of headless.
How do I make sure the app is executed on the desktop, even if I run the command from a remote ssh connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DISPLAY` environment variable to start a GUI program on the remote computer. However, it is not shown to you, but rather opens on the active X-session with address `:0`, which is the default for the first X-session. To enable, use

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

For more information, see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126).

---

If you also want to see it, use `ssh -X` to log on that computer. For more information, see this relevant [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine/12772#12772).