# How to Run a GUI Application on Remote Server's X11 Display via SSH

Tags: ssh, x11

In this picture, on my virtual-machine I have Redhat running with an SSH server, and I'm remotely logged-in via SSH. I want to run `gedit` via SSH but have the `gedit` window open on the remote Redhat server, not the machine from which I run the SSH client. I don't want to use `ssh -X root@192.168.100.195`, I want to open `gedit` on the ssh server's display via ssh client.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing it like this instead:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gedit
```

Or even, just:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Before you run your commands.

The reason you see `Cannot open display:` with no display specified after the `:` is because `$DISPLAY` is not set, as `ssh` isn't aware you have an X session running.

You said you don't want to use `ssh -X` (X11 Forwarding), but in case others end up here, you might also look into [using X11 forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine), if you want the GUI application to display on your local (client) machine rather than the remote (server) machine.