# X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting

Tags: x11, login, privileges

After I login to a server using `ssh` and try to initiate `X11` I got the below error message:

```
$startx
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
xinit: giving up
xinit: server error
```

by checking the `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`, it shows

```
allowed_users=console
```

I am wondering how to fix this issue. I also don't have the root privilege for some setting changes.

Comment: did you try changing the word `console` to `anybody` yet ?

Comment: It turns out I don't have root privilege to make that change. It seems also not suggested for security reasons.

Comment: What are you trying to do?   Please respond to [Thomas Dickey’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304302/80216#304333).

Comment: If you aren't root, you aren't the systems administrator and are therefore not the person who should be making systemwide configuration changes. Perhaps you should talk to the person who *does* have root privileges and ask them why you're not allowed to `startx`.

Comment: If you want to run an X application on the remote host, it may be more useful to start the X server on the local host, then login to the remote with X forwarding e.g 'ssh -XY remote'. SSH should then set the DISPLAY environment variable properly, such that any X application run on the remote will be displayed in the local X server. (This may not work as well, for some OpenGL applications. afaict it works OK for most other applications, including the Chrome/Chromium browser)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are *trying* to do:

- if you *had* permissions, at best you would get X running, using the console of the computer which you connected to for its display.  You wouldn't get X running on the local machine from which you ran `ssh`.
- if you logged in *on* the console, you would have permissions to `startx` — still on that display.
- if you are trying to run an X application on the server, displaying *on* your local machine, the way to do this is to have X running *on* the local machine, and using X forwarding (establishing an authorized connection) run the application via ssh, displaying on your local machine.  You do not have to `startx` on the remote machine for *that*.

Further reading:

- [X Over SSH2 - A Tutorial](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html)
- [How to forward X over SSH from Ubuntu machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine)

Answer (score 2):

```
dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

This will work.

Comment: How will it work? What does it do?

Comment: @Zv_oDD Assuming a certain dpkg configuration, e.g by default, the shell command may result in a dialogue window being displayed. The dialogue window may present an option for graphically selecting, "Users allowed to start the X server," with options, "Root only", "Console Users Only," or "Anybody." Of course, "Root Only," might not be recommended.

As the same dialogue window denotes, this pertains to concerns attendant of running the X server as setuid.

Comment: Thanks, now this answer is far better.

Answer (score 1):

For my Debian jessie, no session manager, only X11, xorg and mwm (Motif window manager), I got this problem only after copying my home folder from another Debian jessie host.  Turns out that when I moved the `~/.Xsession` to a temporary `~/old` folder, it corrected the issue.

```
# mv ~/.Xsession ~/old
```

In addition, I found out that *gnu-screen* would generate "X: user not authorized to run the x server, aborting."

Comment: As well as with GNU screen, this may also occur when running startx under tmux. Perhaps it has something to do with PTY allocation, broadly. There may be a partial workaround in running 'startx' directly from the login pty.