# How to run Google Chrome or Chromium on a remote ssh session?

Tags: ssh, x11, osx, chrome, ssh-tunneling

I have CentOS 7 in the cloud where I can do only remotely `ssh root@docean.com`.

But remotely, how can I run a session of Google Chrome or Chromium on it and see the GUI remotely to browse remotely?

I have already tried all the references but none solve it. I am connecting from OSX 10.12x to CentOS 7.

**Step 1:**

```
$ which xauth
/usr/bin/xauth
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#X11Forwarding no
$ systemctl restart sshd.service
$ systemctl stop iptables.service
```

**Step 2:  Failing?**

```
$ echo $DISPLAY

$ ssh -v -X root@docean.com
...
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
...
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xclock
xclock Error: Can't open display:

$ chromium-browser https://icanhazip.com
[28207:28207:0323/200459.551890:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(272)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
[28207:28207:0323/200459.557234:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(272)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```

Comment: What are you connecting from? Is it a Unix-like machine (Linux, *BSD, macOS...) or a Windows machine?

Comment: See my above EDIT section please. still failing from OSX to CentOS7.

Comment: Actually I've two linux machines connected via `ssh -X` and chromium is the only application opening on the wrong display, xterm or firefox open in the correct one, as if chromium isn't honouring the environment `DISPLAY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing an X11 Server on the Mac Side.  An X11 server used to ship with OS X, but doesn't anymore, however the [XQuartz Project](http://www.xquartz.org) provides working client and server libraries and binaries for OS X (even Sierra).

You can run `xauth`, and `export DISPLAY=blah`, and `xclock` all you want, but if you don't actually have an X-compatible display server (and the display on OS X is **not** X-Windows), it will all be for naught.

XQuartz is also [Apple's official recommendation for X on OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341), too.

Once you get [XQuartz installed](https://www.xquartz.org/), you should have a much better experience X-Forwarding applications, and at that point some of the other answers in this thread should get you going.

Answer (score 9):

First you need uncomment this lines in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on server:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

The second step is connect to server with `-X` and execute Chromium

```
ssh -X user@hostname chromium
```

You will see it on client computer.

Comment: you have a firewall?

Comment: See my above EDIT section please. still failing.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Finally something which worked flawlessly!

On my Raspbian the conf file is not `/etc/sshd_config`, but `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and the final command is `ssh -X user@hostname chromium-browser`

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try X forwarding option in ssh? ssh -X or ssh -Y, or enable remote desktop service

Comment: See my above EDIT section please. still failing.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is using X11 forwaring, as others suggested, you need to have xserver installed on the <strike>remote</strike> local machine.

Well explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/222357

Edit: as @Jakuje correctly pointed out, on remote machine there's no need to install xserver

Comment: no. You need the X server on the **local** machine.

Comment: xauth has to be installed on the remote machine

Comment: So what are you trying to ssh *from* - if you do "echo $DISPLAY" on your local machine, do you get ":0.0"?

Comment: See my above EDIT section please. still failing.