# AWS EC2 forwarding google-chrome to Mac Big Sure xquartz: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found; libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Tags: ubuntu, x11, chrome, macos, aws

Attempting to run Chrome `google-chrome` v96.0.4664.45 from an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 instance, and redirect display to my Macbook running Big Sur and xquartz v2.8.1.

Why am I getting the errors below?

The application launches, but is painfully slow. xeyes, xclock, and xcalc all work.

UPDATE1:

Seems an issue with Mac Big Sur and xquartz. See:

https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/issues/144

UBUNTU:

```
sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

ERROR

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed ot load driver: swrast
```

MACBOOK

- X11 server (xquartz) installed
- Connection command:
  `ssh -X -i qwerty.pem ubuntu@192.0.2.0`

REFERENCES

1. [How to forward X over SSH to run graphics applications remotely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely)

Comment: Missing swrast : Install `libgl1-mesa-dri`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=swrast&searchon=contents

Comment: @KnudLarsen Nope. Still getting error after install.